# Why `git show` doesn't provide info about branches for redirected stdout?

Tags: git

Here are two commands with result examples:

```
$ git show

commit 6f367e05cc6457fd0c0fc59fe0476db06cffb383 (HEAD -> master, tag: v7.32, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 94ecf1d8 f3ea52b0
Author: Pupkin <pupkin@server.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 13 12:49:12 2019 +0700

    Some commit description.
```

```
$ echo `git show`

commit 6f367e05cc6457fd0c0fc59fe0476db06cffb383 Merge: 94ecf1d8 f3ea52b0 Author: Pupkin <pupkin@server.com> Date: Fri Dec 13 12:49:12 2019 +0700 Some commit description.
```

The important difference: in the second result no information about branches - *"(HEAD -> master, tag: v7.32, origin/master, origin/HEAD)"*.

I also tried redirections of stdout and stderr to each other, redirect to file, grep, some other constructions. The same result, in the console showing everything, in other cases - no branches info.

Why so?

And how to compel git to return the whole message?

Comment: There are similar questions but I just can't find them. In the 2nd case, you need to use `git show --decorate=short` or `git show --decorate=full`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. The second question is solved. `--decorate` key works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said [@ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) in the comment above, I need to use the key `--decorate` with the command.

From the [Git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorateshortfullautono):

> --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
>
> Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If short is specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/ will not be printed. If full is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. If auto is specified, then if the output is going to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if short were given, otherwise no ref names are shown. The default option is **short**.

But I'm pretty sure that by default uses `auto` instead `short` as it said in manual.

This question is solved.